# Проверка ключа массива на существование

Tags: php, массивы

Хочу проверить ключ на существование в массиве $arr с помощью тернарного оператора. И если **true**, то вывести на экран этот ключ.

```
<?php

$arr = array("test" => 1, "some" => 2);

echo "test" ? array_key_exists("test", $arr) : echo "такого ключа нет";

?>
```

Но выдаёт ошибку при написании. Но а где здесь ошибка?

Comment: два раза echo? ошибку надо указывать.

Comment: обычно так пишут `echo array_key_exists("test", $arr) ? 'ключ есть' : 'ключа нет';`

Comment: а как сделать чтобы вместо 'ключ есть' вывелось имя этого ключа? Ну только не писать прямо "test".

Comment: никак не сделать, вы же где то берете его перед проверкой, значит можно вставить и внутрь 'ключ есть'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильная в корне конструкция. Логически она должна выглядеть так:

```
echo (что-то);
```

Скобки необязательны, но так для вас будет понятнее. Теперь внутрь скобок вставляем тернарный оператор `array_key_exists("test", $arr) ? 'ключ есть' : 'ключа нет'` который буквально обозначает `true ? действие_для_true : действие_иначе;`

Получается, скобки заодно убираем:

```
echo array_key_exists("test", $arr) ? 'ключ есть' : 'ключа нет';
```

Рабочий пример: http://ideone.com/H68pwa

С выводом ключа  из переменной итоговое:

```
$arr = array("test" => 1, "some" => 2);
$key = 'test';
echo array_key_exists($key, $arr) ? "ключ $key есть" : 'ключа нет';
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы вместо 'ключ есть' вывелось имя этого ключа? Ну только не писать прямо "test".

Comment: @Sven обновил пример

Comment: да, понятно, спасибо.